# What's the most efficient way to store data to multiple refs in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's see the next situation:

If we create an user, we have to create a new client, a new user, and a new, inital project for the user.

```js
db = {
  users: {},
  clients: {},
  projects: {}
};

const usersRef = firebase.database().ref("/users");
const clientsRef = firebase.database().ref("/clients");
const projectsRef = firebase.database().ref("/projects");
```

To keep the code clean, and separated, we can create three functions:

```
const newUserToDb = name => {
  const newUser = usersRef.push();
  newUser.set({name});
};

const newClientToDb = name => {
  const newClient = clientsRef.push();
  newClient.set({name});
};

const newProjectToDb = name => {
  const newProject = projectsRef.push();
  newProject.set({name});
};

const createUserToDb = (userName, clientName, projectName) => {
  newUserToDb(userName);
  newClientToDb(clientName);
  newProjectToDb(projectName);
};
```

To make all the changes in one place, but make the code less separated:

```
const createUserToDb = (userName, clientName, projectName) => {
  const userId = usersRef.push().key;
  const clientId = clientsRef.push().key;
  const projectId = projectsRef.push().key;

  const updates = {};

  updates[`/users/${userId}`] = userName;
  updates[`/clients/${clientId}`] = clientName;
  updates[`/projects/${projectId}`] = projectName;

  firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
};
```

Is there any important difference between the two solutions above? Which is more efficient?

Comment: In the first solution all updates are done seperately and can fail/succees seperately. In the second it's all or nothing: either all update succeed or all updates fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important difference to the above approach is atomicity. In the first scenario, the individual collection or documents update will succeed or fail without affecting other updates. In the second scenario, all the updates will succeed else none will.

I don't think efficiency is the right term to be used for comparing the above scenarios, its more of the business/use case which will define which one you need to use

Comment: Agreed on both counts: there is no significant efficiency difference, but the multi-location update ensures that all writes are either accepted or rejected as one. I'd typically use a multi-location update to *write* the data myself, but ensure that my code that *reads* the data can also handle partial updates.

Answer (score 1):

The first way seems more separated and explicit which would probably be easier for other developers to understand.